# Define a Deque into LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, tree, stack, deque

I am reviewing a code pre-order binary tree using iterative method. Looks like they do:

**Deque < TreeNode > stack = new LinkedList< TreeNode >();**

Why not just do:

**Deque < TreeNode > stack = new Deque < TreeNode >();**

I dont see they use something particularly from LinkedList been used in the code.

```
public class PreOrder {  
  public static List<Integer> preorderTraversalIterative(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> preorder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (root == null) {
      return preorder;
    }
    Deque<TreeNode> stack = new LinkedList<TreeNode>(); //Why?
    stack.offerFirst(root);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
      TreeNode cur = stack.pollFirst();
      if (cur.right != null) {
        stack.offerFirst(cur.right);
      }
      if (cur.left != null) {
        stack.offerFirst(cur.left);
      }
      preorder.add(cur.key);
    }
    return preorder;
  }
}
```

Comment: My bad. When I tried to compile. The compiler already complaint for: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instatiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Deque` is an interface; you cannot instantiate it without providing an implementation for **all** of its `abstract` methods, which is what `LinkedList` does already.